# access separately dynamic input text control text using ng repeat in angular js

Tags: angularjs

[This image shows how I have dynamically created rows according the varying no.of tasks retrieved from the database using the ng-repeat directive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCwza.png)

```html
      <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
       <td>{{task}}</td>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="day1"></td>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="day2"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="day3"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="day4"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="day5"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="day6"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="day7"></td>
      </tr>
```

I have used this code to create those rows. The no.of rows depends on the tasks which are retrieved from the database.
**My question is** that when a user fills the information in the above input boxes, how can I get that data by individually accessing each input control? Since even if I name the input box, many boxes will have the same name as it is in ng-repeat. 
The no.of tasks are dynamic:

```js
 var fetch = angular.module('myApp', []);

 fetch.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'getTasks.php'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // Store response data
  $scope.tasks = response.data;
  });
```

So how can I link the dynamic no.of tasks with the fixed no.of days
This is the response data that has being fetched through PHP

```html
<?php
....
$sql = "select * from `assigned_projects` where `EID`='$getid' and `PID`='$p'";
    $res = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $data = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
  $temp = array();
  $temp = explode(",",$row['Tasks']);
  $data = array_merge($data,$temp);  
 }
    echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
```

Please tell me if my question is unclear or whether any other snippet of code is required to make this problem clearer

Comment: Each task has 7 days related to it?

Comment: @BarouchKandov Yes Sir.

Comment: I think the answer below will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the days inputs linked to the particular record, something like:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="task_Record in tasks">
    <td>{{task_Record.task}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="task_Record.day1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="task_Record.day2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="task_Record.day3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="task_Record.day4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="task_Record.day5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="task_Record.day6"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="task_Record.day7"></td>
  </tr>
```

so your $scope variable would be:

```
$scope.tasks = [{task:<value>,
                 day1:<value>,
                 day2:<value>,
                 day3:<value>,
                 day4:<value>,
                 day5:<value>,
                 day6:<value>,
                 day7:<value>},...
               ] ;
```

Comment: Please check my edited question. The tasks are dynamic in number. Can I generalize this array using any method? like if there is a function like "foreach" task?

Comment: Well, it would be natural to assume that you get your list from somewhere, say, your DB. The array object (i.e. `$scope.tasks`) will have any number of entries (being one entry a structure including all 8 field: ID, day1 to day7). The advantage of `ng-repeat` is that it will generate a table with as many rows as entries in your array. Now, if you wish to programmatically add an entry, you can use the `push` or `splice` methods.

Answer (score 0):

See this below code.

> First of all you need to manage your data properly. Check the
>   $scope.tasks array. It is array of tasks. And each task contains 7
>   days data.
>
> Now the second task is to iterate through these tasks with the help of
>   ng-repeat. Here you will get the data in the task. As each task will
>   contain the day details, you will access them with the help of the dot
>   operator.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
            <!--<td>{{task}}</td>-->
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="task.day1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="task.day2"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="task.day3"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="task.day4"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="task.day5"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="task.day6"></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="task.day7"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.tasks = [
                {
                    'day1': '1.1',
                    'day2': '1.2',
                    'day3': '1.3',
                    'day4': '1.4',
                    'day5': '1.5',
                    'day6': '1.6',
                    'day7': '1.7',
                },
                {
                    'day1': '2.1',
                    'day2': '2.2',
                    'day3': '2.3',
                    'day4': '2.4',
                    'day5': '2.5',
                    'day6': '2.6',
                    'day7': '2.7',
                },
                {
                    'day1': '3.1',
                    'day2': '3.2',
                    'day3': '3.3',
                    'day4': '3.4',
                    'day5': '3.5',
                    'day6': '3.6',
                    'day7': '3.7',
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check my edited question. The tasks are dynamic in number. Can I generalize this array using any method? like if there is a function like "foreach" task?

Comment: In this I have taken dummy data. I'm not sure what data comes in the response. Can you please share the response data?

Comment: What you can do is write your api to return the data in format as $scope.tasks. Or you need to convert it in this required format in the angularjs code.

Comment: @AnujaKulkarni: not this, I need json data which is coming to the angularjs side.

Comment: @AnujaKulkarni: I need to know what data comes in $scope.tasks.

Comment: It is in the form: $scope.tasks = ['high level design', 'coding', 'testing', ... 'sick leave']; The array elements depend on the ones retrieved from the db. But overall they come as simply arrays (not key value paired)

Comment: @AnujaKulkarni: Looks it is 1D array. We can fill data for a single week with the help of this, but not other weeks, It should be 2D array.

Comment: Can you recommend what the format of the 2D array should be? I'll try to get the data in that format

Comment: You can check my answer, You can make your api to return data in the format like $scope.tasks. The array of object will serve the purpose.